# Laravel Carbon::now() method returning null on ubuntu server

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu-18.04

I have User model when I tried to return all users like this query

```
 $users = User::all();

    $userCollections = (object)collect([]);
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        $userCollections['name'] = $user->name,
        $userCollections['date'] = $user->created_at; // here working fine in local but in server
//returning null array like this [] and its in database like this -> 2020-06-30 13:11:01
        ...
        ..
        etc ...
    }
```

That's work fine, but when I return this from ubuntu server - the response will be like this

```
"created_at": [],
```

Also, if I tried to return `Carbon::now()` the server return null array like this `[]` and in local working fine.

Comment: Yes, miss click sorry, anyway It is written correctly in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the php version from php7.4 into php7.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$userCollections = User::all()->mapWithKeys(function ($user) {
    return [['name' => $user->name, 'date' => $user->created_at]];
})
```

Laravel [mapWithKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys)

Comment: Same problem, Also when I tried to `Carbon::now()' its working fine on local but on ubuntu server returning `null`